# Null array of buttons supposed to be set

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I don't understand why in my code I get a :

> null reference object

when i try to click on my buttons.

```
buttonMenuOption = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption);
Button[] buttonsOption = new Button[nbObjects];
buttonsOption[0] = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption0);
buttonsOption[1] = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption1);
buttonMenuOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.graph_option);
            for (int i = 0; i < nbObjects; i++) {
                final int j = i;
                    buttonsOption[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //Do stuff
                          }
                    });
             }
     });
```

To resume my code, there is an option button in my main activity, when I press it, it changes the layout then there are multiples buttons to activate a color picker.

Why is my `buttonsOption[0]` a null reference?

***Update***

```
buttonMenuOption = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption)
buttonMenuOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
     setContentView(R.layout.graph_option);
     Button[] buttonsOption = new Button[nbObjects];
        for (int i = 0; i < nbObjects; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            buttonsOption[0] = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption0);
            buttonsOption[1] = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption1);
            buttonsOption[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Do stuff
                      }
                });
         }
 });
```

Comment: i guess you are changing the content view which might not contain the same buttons. So in the for loop use findViewById.

Comment: Please add your `xml` code and logcat also.

Comment: XML + logcat added

Comment: You were right, I don't understand why i had the error. Anyway thank you.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], but I would guess the view is loaded after you are trying to get the `Button`, this is the most common error when a `findViewById` using the correct value return `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem occurred from

```
buttonsOption[0] = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption0);
buttonsOption[1] = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption1);
```

which are declared before related layout initialize.

so you may have to declare button reference after `setContentView(R.layout.graph_option);` like below

```
    buttonMenuOption = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption);
 final Button[] buttonsOption = new Button[nbObjects];

buttonMenuOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.graph_option);
         buttonsOption[0] = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption0);//change here
         buttonsOption[1] = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption1);// change here
            for (int i = 0; i < nbObjects; i++) {
                final int j = i;
                    buttonsOption[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //Do stuff
                          }
                    });
             }
     });
```

Comment: Wow...I was talking with someone while typing...  You should add more content to your answer. Highlight the problem and what you have done to make it work. _like below_ is a too broad ;)

Comment: @AxelH ohh.. ok done answer edited!

Comment: This is always better to post an explanation with the code (the comments are a nice touch by the way ;) ) It will be easier to understand and of course, it gain in interest.

Comment: @AxelH yes your right, next time I'll take it in mind!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `findViewById` before you `setContentView()`, there is no view to find other view in. You need to first set your XML as your activity's view then you can call `findViewById`

Or you can do things a bit differently, like that

```
buttonMenuOption = findViewById(R.id.buttonOption);
Button[] buttonsOption = new Button[nbObjects];
final View newContentView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.graph_option, null);
buttonsOption[0] = newContentView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOption0);
buttonsOption[1] = newContentView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOption1);
buttonMenuOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(newContentView);
            for (int i = 0; i < nbObjects; i++) {
                final int j = i;
                    buttonsOption[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //Do stuff
                          }
                    });
             }
     });
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it because you have declared an array of buttons but not declared any button for the index of the array?

If buttonsOption[0] is null, I would declare the array and then the button.

```
Button[] buttonsOption = new Button[nbObjects];

for(int i=0; i<nbObjects;i++){
    buttonOption[i] = new Button();
}
```